# LED bulbs temperature safety

Tags: wiring

I changed my bathroom ceiling fixture from a three light dome which held three **9w 0.1A 2700k 800lm** bulbs to an **18w 0.2A 5000k 1800lm** flush LED light.

The only problem I'm having is that the new flush mount light seems to get up to 113 degrees Fahrenheit ( *working temperature* ) so it is warm to the touch.

It has a little notch in the top part of the molding for air flow but I'm curious what the safe temperature is for the insulation on the 14/2 wire.

I previous had two incandescent domed lights in the kitchen that burnt up the wires, the coating flaked off with any movement so I want to try to prevent that from happening again.

Comment: What kind of 14/2 are we talking about here?  Old cloth-wrapped NM or BX? Modern thermoplastic NM-B, ACTHH, THHN, or MC? Something else?  Can you get us a make and model for the new fixture please for that matter?

Comment: NM I'm pretty sure, I'm in a North American home that was built in 1982

Comment: NM-B you mean that is? Perhaps you can shoot us a photo of the inside of the fixture box, or of some representative wiring in the house for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

NM-B cable is rated for 15A at 60C.

60C is 140F.